# How to dynamically change values for input number and validate the data inside it?

Tags: javascript, input, numbers

I'm trying to create some dynamic code for my website using JavaScript.
In my code I have a form for creating new events, including number of people needed for this event. Here is the code for my form in HTML:

```
<td align="center">Number of people:<br /><select id="ppl_select" name="ppl_select" onchange="checkPpl(this); setMinMax(this)">
    <option value="8" selected="selected">8</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="0">Other</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="number" min="1" max="30" name="other_ppl" id="other_ppl" disabled="disabled" />
    </td>
```

The last input with id="other_ppl" is for non-usual events, so it will be visible only when you select "Other" option from the drop-down list.

Also I have some input fields to calculate all the data, after selecting one of the option above:

```
<td align="right">Tanks: <input align="right" width="30" type="number" id="tanks_num" value="2" /><p id="max_tanks"></p></td>
    <td align="right">DPS: <input align="right" width="30" type="number" id="dps_num" value="4" /><p id="max_dps"></p></td>
    <td align="right">Healers: <input align="right" width="30" type="number" id="heal_num" value="2" /><p id="max_heals"></p></td>
```

All these fields should be calculated and change dynamically after selecting one of the options from the drop-down list thanks to this code:

```
function checkPpl(obj) {
    var input = document.getElementById("other_ppl");
    input.disabled = obj.value != "0";
}

function setMinMax(obj) {
    var num_tanks = document.getElementById("tanks_num");
    var num_dps = document.getElementById("dps_num");
    var num_heal = document.getElementById("heal_num");

    var max_tanks = document.getElementById("max_tanks");
    var max_dps = document.getElementById("max_dps");
    var max_heals = document.getElementById("max_heals");
    if($(this).value == '8')
    {
        num_tanks.setAttribute("value", 2);
        num_tanks.setAttribute("max", 2);
        max_tanks.innerHTML = "Maximum: " + (num_tanks.value);

        num_dps.setAttribute("value", 4);
        num_dps.setAttribute("max", 4);

        num_heal.setAttribute("value", 2);
        num_heal.setAttribute("max", 2);
    }
    else if ($(this).value == '16')
    {
        num_tanks.setAttribute("value", 2);
        num_tanks.setAttribute("max", 2);
        max_tanks.innerHTML = "Maximum: " + (num_tanks.value);

        num_dps.setAttribute("value", 10);
        num_dps.setAttribute("max", 10);

        num_heal.setAttribute("value", 4);
        num_heal.setAttribute("max", 4);
    }
}
```

The thing is this script is not working properly. There is no data displayed next to "Tanks" field (with

attribute) the value in input fields are not changing, to be honest I have no idea if this script is working or not. Usually I'm not using Javascript/jQuery because my knowledge about these languages is not enough for my needs, but slowly I'm trying to learn it and this is my first script written from scratch. Please, help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why mix jquery and DOM functions? Also be careful not to have two nodes with the same id in your page.

Comment: `$(this).value` won't work. `$(this)` is a jQuery object, `value` is a DOM property. It should either be `this.value` or `$(this).val()`. Also, `this` should be `obj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to your function is named `obj`, not `this`, so you should be using that to get the value. And `.value` is a DOM property, not a jQuery property, so you shouldn't wrap it with `$()`.

```
function setMinMax(obj) {
    var num_tanks = document.getElementById("tanks_num");
    var num_dps = document.getElementById("dps_num");
    var num_heal = document.getElementById("heal_num");

    var max_tanks = document.getElementById("max_tanks");
    var max_dps = document.getElementById("max_dps");
    var max_heals = document.getElementById("max_heals");
    if(obj.value == '8')
    {
        num_tanks.setAttribute("value", 2);
        num_tanks.setAttribute("max", 2);
        max_tanks.innerHTML = "Maximum: " + (num_tanks.value);

        num_dps.setAttribute("value", 4);
        num_dps.setAttribute("max", 4);

        num_heal.setAttribute("value", 2);
        num_heal.setAttribute("max", 2);
    }
    else if (obj.value == '16')
    {
        num_tanks.setAttribute("value", 2);
        num_tanks.setAttribute("max", 2);
        max_tanks.innerHTML = "Maximum: " + (num_tanks.value);

        num_dps.setAttribute("value", 10);
        num_dps.setAttribute("max", 10);

        num_heal.setAttribute("value", 4);
        num_heal.setAttribute("max", 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's it the changes in your code that will do your task.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       // On selecting an option in select dropdown
       $("#ppl_select").change(function(){
           var selectedValue = $(this).val();  // Get value of selected option

           if(selectedValue == "0"){   // if selected option is 0 (other)
              $("#other_ppl).removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable other people textbox
           }

           setMinMax(selectedValue); // Now call your setMinMax function passing with
                                     // selected option value
        });
   });


    function setMinMax(value) {
        var num_tanks = document.getElementById("tanks_num");
        var num_dps = document.getElementById("dps_num");
        var num_heal = document.getElementById("heal_num");

        var max_tanks = document.getElementById("max_tanks");
        var max_dps = document.getElementById("max_dps");
        var max_heals = document.getElementById("max_heals");
        if(value == '8')
        {
            num_tanks.setAttribute("value", 2);
            num_tanks.setAttribute("max", 2);
            max_tanks.innerHTML = "Maximum: " + (num_tanks.value);

            num_dps.setAttribute("value", 4);
            num_dps.setAttribute("max", 4);

            num_heal.setAttribute("value", 2);
            num_heal.setAttribute("max", 2);
        }
        else if(value == '16')
        {
            num_tanks.setAttribute("value", 2);
            num_tanks.setAttribute("max", 2);
            max_tanks.innerHTML = "Maximum: " + (num_tanks.value);

            num_dps.setAttribute("value", 10);
            num_dps.setAttribute("max", 10);

            num_heal.setAttribute("value", 4);
            num_heal.setAttribute("max", 4);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed? Most of us can't run `diff` in our heads.

Comment: On selecting an option from select dropdown, am taking its value and checking it whether its value is 0 or not. If it is 0 then am enabling the other_pp1 textbox. And, then setting the min & max values by calling setMinMax function passing selected option value to it. That's it..!!

Comment: Put the explanation in the answer.